# WebSphere Commerce IDResGen query

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

I'm trying to load em spots using massload. I'm finding the internal alias method of idresgen.bat is only resolving the internal alias for foreign key references, but I need to use the value in dmelementnvp value column which doesn't have a foreign key reference.

In the sample code below the last dmelementnvp definition is rejected with an error that value could not be resolved. Does anyone know how to resolve the emspot id to populate the value column required?

```
<emspot 
    emspot_id="@emspot_id_1" 
    storeent_id="&MAR_STOREENT_ID;" 
    name="Home_BestSellers" 
    description="Display catalog entry recommendations from Coremetrics Intelligent Offer on the home page." 
    usagetype="MARKETING" 
    supportedtypes="P" 
/>
<dmactivity
    dmactivity_id="@dmactivity_bestseller1"
    storeent_id="&MAR_STOREENT_ID;"
    name="HomePageBestSellersActivity"
    description="The test activity for the home page best sellers"
    published="1"
    state="1"
    behavior="1"
    dmcampaign_id="@campaign_initial_launch"
/>

<dmelement
    dmelement_id="@dmactivity_bestseller_elem1"
    name="Flow0.0"
    dmeletemplate_id="6"
    dmactivity_id="@dmactivity_bestseller1"
    sequence="0"
/>

<dmelement
    dmelement_id="@dmactivity_bestseller_elem2"
    name="Coremetrics Target"
    dmeletemplate_id="339"
    dmactivity_id="@dmactivity_bestseller1"
    sequence="1500"
    parent="Flow0.0"
/>

<dmelement
    dmelement_id="@dmactivity_bestseller_elem3"
    name="Espot Target"
    dmeletemplate_id="105"
    dmactivity_id="@dmactivity_bestseller1"
    sequence="1000"
    parent="Flow0.0"
/>

<dmelementnvp
    dmelement_id="@dmactivity_bestseller_elem2"
    name="zoneIdList"
    value="ZoneA"
/>

<dmelementnvp
    dmelement_id="@dmactivity_bestseller_elem3"
    name="emsId"
    value="@emspot_id_1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this question to IBM Software Support.